# Error: socket hang up in Postman request with docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, postman

I run NodeJs application with nodemon and try make some request to API and everything is ok. But when I build docker image and start comtainer, my Postman stops and can not send any requests and write **Could not get response Error: socket hang up**
[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XN6C.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  Can you edit the question and [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and share the code of what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It was wrong connection to MongoDB